# Where should this code live - in my Activity or my Adapter?

Tags: android, android-activity, adapter

I'm looking for guidance as to how to modularize my code. I have an activity and a listAdapter and they are getting pretty complex. I'm not sure what code should live where and how much knowledge each of these 2 classes should have of each other. How do you decide whether to put code in an activity or its adapter? And what patterns do you use to keep these classes as lean as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description is too generic, so I cannot give you an exact answer (would be useful to explain why they are getting bigger and bigger, what is the extra code good for).

But generically speaking, just think about what each class supposed to do. The "Activity" (as I see it), is a main controller, it "knows everybody", and it connects the other components together (the ListView with the list adapter). The list adapter's purpose is simply to map data to views. If they are getting bigger, extract new (utility) classes.

For example assume a big part of the code in ListAdapter formats timestamps (eg. takes timestamp as long value, and based on current time creates a string like "2 hours ago"). Then it makes sense to create a new utility class called TimeFormat (with a constructor which takes a context, you'll need it later to fetch string resources). Then the ListAdapter will create an instance of this class.

Another example would be data saving. In that case you could create a class called "Model" or "Document" (again with a constructor taking a "Context" instance). It would be responsible (for example) to load the data by parsin XML files, and to save the data by generating XML files. In this case this class would be instantiated by the activity.

Also note that the ListAdapter should really do what it supposed to do: create/setup views based on data. It should never depend on other views (in other views it should work with any ListView in any layout file). So if you have "findViewById" call, which access a view outside of the ListView (or the ListView itself), then that code should be moved to the activity.

Also, when in doubt you can try to find an open source application, which is relatively mature, and does something similarn (and see how that is solving the problem).

Answer (score 1):

Per the [adapater documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) in android

> An Adapter object acts as a bridge between an AdapterView and the underlying data for that view. The Adapter provides access to the data items. The Adapter is also responsible for making a View for each item in the data set.

So if your code has to do with getting the data to display or creating the views, then it goes in the adapter. Everything else goes in the Activity or else where. If you're spending a lot of code retrieving the information you want to display, consider using some sort of [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) class. Note that loader classes can be accessed from API Levels less than 3.0 using the [android compatibility package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).